# How to run vowpal wabbit in daemon mode

Tags: daemon, vowpalwabbit

I want to run vowpal wabbit in daemon mode training. I found the stackoverflow link [Read data from memory in Vowpal Wabbit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846454/read-data-from-memory-in-vowpal-wabbit) , but did not get how to specify model file name. What I am doing is run

```
vw --save_resume -f ob/e/nsefut/VWDaemon/model.vw --quiet --daemon --port 26542
```

and then send examples. What I did get from the link is that I have to send tags starting "save" to make vw understand that its a training data. So, I sent it as

```
 echo '2 save| b:1.0 c:2.8 ' | netcat localhost 26542
```

But I cant locate the model file. It would be really great if there is some tutorial for it.

## edit:

Plus in between training in daemon mode, I also want to be able to see the coefficients till that point.

Comment: I suppose there are several questions in this topic:
1. " I cant locate the model file" - bcs you must send `save` or `save_filename` to vw to instruct it to dump the current model state.
2. "I want to run vowpal wabbit in daemon mode training". VW always works in training mode unless you specified `-t` in command line.
3. How to get examples only predicted? - send them without labels like `echo ' mytest| b:1.0 c:2.8 ' | netcat localhost 26542` and look for mytest tags in predictions (`-p` param)

Comment: and do we need to start n vw instances ( daemon mode with a port ) for n model training?

Comment: yes. vw is able to train only one model. e.g. only one regressor with feature weights. I guess it still may be tuned (by changing C++ code) to perform several different ML algorithms one after another over every example it gets using the same regressor (e.g. feature space coeffs), like `--oaa` is based on sequential call of `GD`. But still there will be only one model as a result. So one instance = one model.

Comment: Hi @truf, when I am sending example to vw, it is returning prediction but the process is not getting terminated. I mean after I have sent the observation with the 'netcat' command I mentioned, I have to do ctrl + c to end the command even after I received prediction. Could you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: VW that run in daemon mode isn't supposed to stop working after receiving test example. Bcs you may test many examples then train then test again, etc. VW daemon must be stopped as described in wiki https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/daemon-example#stopping-the-daemon   Ctrl+c is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `echo 'save' | netcat localhost 26542` to instruct vw to dump the current regressor coefficients into the model file. As for obtaining coeffs values pls refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31146894/841424). In short: you can't.

Comment: Even if `--readable_model` was supported in daemon mode it may be impossible to use in some cases. In this mode vw stores in RAM a string title for every newly encountered feature. So it may require too much RAM if your `-b` value is big and you're playing with `-q --cubic --interactions`. I've developed a small add-on for VW that enables it to "demangle" model files. In this mode VW loads a model file, reads train data, checks if every feature has non-zero weight, prints it and put weight to zero if it so. Thus it require same amount of RAM, but 2 passes other same dataset.

Comment: And what I wrote, is that correct? if I send tag starting with "save" , those will be the only ones used in training right?, The ones I send without any tags or so will be used just for prediction.

Comment: "save" must be not a tag, but label. So it shouldn't touch "|". You don't need to specify any data with "save". Just send "save" as whole example. Send it between examples whenever you need it. It won't be used for training or prediction as it has no data. I suspect, if you specify data with example that has "save" label then this data will be just ignored.

Comment: So, the command I ran will just be used for training? Rather my question is can I use the same vw daemon mode command to both train and predict (test only predict) ?

Comment: Well, it's easy to tweak VW to work in such way, but i'm not sure if it'll work like that from the box in all modes (gd, svm, nn, etc). In general training is a set of following steps: predict, compare with label and get loss, update regressor weights. And testing is just one predict step. If you send VW example without label it certainly couldn't use it for learning. So, run vw in train mode and throw unlabeled examples to it - they'll be just predicted. The only problem is to get results out. I suppose if you specify -p it will save predictions for both training and testing examples. So you

Comment: might need to filter them out by example tags. Recall VW's generic example format: `label tag| |namespace feature:weight`